# JPanel disappearing when changing the text of a JButton added to it

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, null-layout-manager

I add a JButton to my JPanel subclass Quiz, and if I change either the text or the font of the button, the Quiz object disappears, showing only the panel underneath it. However, if I change the text or font before adding the button, everything works fine.

setupGraphics() gets called after the Quiz is added to the view hierarchy

```
public void setupGraphics() {
    this.setBackground(Color.red);
    setLayout(null);
    a.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 200);
    add(a);
    a.setText("Hi");
}
```

If I change the code to this:

```
public void setupGraphics() {
    this.setBackground(Color.red);
    setLayout(null);
    a.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 200);
    a.setText("Hi");
    add(a);
}
```

then it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use an appropriate [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Order should not matter, since Swing components are smart enough to paint themselves when a property is changed. So the problem is in the context of how you invoke this method. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score -1):

add(a);
    a.setText("Hi"); --> you are adding the button to the panel and then setting the text. That's y it is not displaying the text. For the second you are setting the text and other attributes and adding the button to the panel.

Comment: `you are adding the button to the panel and then setting the text. That's y it is not displaying the text.` - it doesn't matter if you set the text after adding the button to the panel. Whenever you change a property of a Swing component the component will invoke revalidate() and repaint() on itself.

Comment: sorry i missed out mentioning the repaint().